# What is the default root directory in "require"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, require

After spending literally hours desperately setting up a simple "require" command, my understanding goes to the following statement: `var example = require("example")` works if there's an `example.js` in `node_modules` directory of the project.

I have, however, problems with `var example = require("./some_folder/example.js")`, which  do because I need only a single JS script to load. Anywhere I put `example.js`, I got an HTTP 500 error, which is perfectly surely originated from the `require` line, as commenting it out makes the code work.

This error occurs even if the entirety of `example.js` is commented out, making it empty and meaning that nothing can go wrong.

Where should I put this file precisely? Which folder is `"./"`?

Is it possible that the lack of `module.exports` makes it unable to work?

Comment: require('foo') refers to a foo module inside of node_modules. A relative path, './foo/something' refers to a path relative to your current file/module. Also, you do not need ".js" at the end of your requires. It's implied.

Comment: @ndugger then that means, if I understood well that I have to properly set up a module, and can't just simply load a bunch of variables and functions to use in another file. I mean, this is what modules do, I'm aware, but it's not as simple that I write them down as I'd usually, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type of requires are there :

1. require('foo') // foo is a node module
2. require('./foo') //foo is a js file in same directory

Comment: By "same directory", do you mean `node_modules`, or the directory where the calling script is?

Comment: Directory where your  js file is.

Comment: Somehow, that still doesn't seem to work. :/ but I tend to accept that this is the right answer and I messed it up.

Comment: Try var example = require("./some_folder/example");